# mod_rewrite beginner

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
site
lib
versions
  /1.0
     /application
     /library
     /public
```

and my site root is `example.com`.

I would like all requests to `example.com` to be redirected to `example.com/versions/1.0/public`, whilst keeping the request URL to `example.com`.

My server is on Dreamhost and with them I simply point my site root to the public folder, but my current client's host doesn't offer this facility. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Also, since I'm using ZendFramework, the `public` folder contains a `.htaccess` file with the following rules I wish to avoid conflicting with.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your root directory should have the intended effect, though there may be a more graceful way of doing it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /versions/1.0/public/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `.htaccess` file in the location you are rewriting to, that uses mod_rewrite, then you can simply rewrite everything unconditionally in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /versions/1.0/public/$1 [L]
```

Once the rewrite occurs then the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory takes over. No additional *conditions* are required. No rewrite-loop.

Of course, if you need to have HTTP access to any files outside of this subdirectory then you will need to include additional *conditions* for each of these, or use an all-encompassing filesystem check. However, since you have previously solved this on other systems by seemingly changing the document root, then this does not seem to be an issue.